# Kasparov emerged the winner every time

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> These were arguably the two greatest players in the history of the game at the peak of their powers going at it in five incredibly hard-fought and very close matches. They played a total of 144 games! **Kasparov emerged the winner every time** (except the aborted match of ‘84), but the total score in the matches was only 73–71 in his favor.

Source: [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-greatest-chess-match-ever-Why/answer/H%C3%A5kon-Hapnes-Strand)

Can you please explain to me the bolded passage. I'm not sure whether I understand it properly given the context. Does it mean that Kasparov was considered to be the favourite but he didn't win the majority of the matches.

Comment: [Kasporov, Garry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garry_Kasparov) was the top rated (in the world) international chess grandmaster for many years. He won a great many games of chess. When someone is widely recognized as the best in the world, they are expected to win.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "emerge the winner" is to win. You can think of the meaning as a shortened form of to "emerge [= come out of, finish] (the competition) (as) the winner." In other words, Kasparov won all five matches.